# Table positioning SASS

Tags: html, sass

I am trying to position some HTML elements into a table using SASS into a table like this:

http://tinypic.com/r/2dkzfao/8

Ideally, I would like to style them without having to change the HTML, so that the content is decoupled from the style. What is the best way to do this?

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="shortcut col-xs-6">
  <div class="keyCombination"> ctrl + c </div>
  <div class="application"> Webstorm </div>
  <div class="description"> Copy </div>
  <div class="operatingSystem"> Windows 8 </div>
</div>
```

And my SASS:

```
.shortcut {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background: #fffc70;
    display: table;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    .keyCombination {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        font-size: 300%;
        border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:left;
    }
    .application {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    }
    .description {
    }
    .operatingSystem {
      border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fs7WSq4NYzempzxaVIMZ?p=preview

Comment: What you have looks reasonably close to what you want. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: It's close, but I can't figure out how to align the operating system section to the bottom and make the three sections on the right extend all the way to the right.

Comment: Take the easy way out and just use an actual table.

Comment: @Petah shame on you for suggesting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.col-xs-6 has padding-right:15px which I guess you don't need. Either remove it or override it so you'll see right side element's border will touch the end of the box.

You can use min-height/height in % to get the alignment you want in right side. For example:

```
.description {
    height: 70%
}
```

Comment: The second part works like a charm, but for the first, I don't want the elements to extend to the right edge of the page, but rather to extend to the right edge of the shortcut div (right now there is a small gap).

Comment: that's because .col-xs-6 has padding-right:15px which I guess you don't need. Either remove it or override it so you'll see right side element's border will touch the end of the box.